# How does Flash know it was opened in two different browser windows?

Tags: flash

I noticed the following when working with some software written in Flash:

When I open the same software in two different browsers (Chrome and Firefox), the first browser says "you just opened this Flash program in another browser".

How did Flash know it was opened in another browser? I thought browsers were isolated? It appears that Flash is a global process?

Does anyone know how to isolate Flash and make it per-browser so I can run two versions of this Flash program concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Player is a global process since you install the software into your computer and then it kicks into action  whenever you open a browser tab with Flash content.

The SWF file is the compiled code that has instructions for what happens in that individual Flash (SWF) content. The installed Flash Player controls access to your computer's operating system (assigning system memory etc).

It's possible for SWF files embedded to communicate with another SWF, but only if both are programmed to  respond to each other. This method is called **[LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html)** and here is an **[example tutorial](http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/08/the-ultimate-guide-to-localconnection-swf-to-air/)**.

I suspect when your SWF when is opened, it's sending out a signal and also looking to receive such a signal. Finally when have two copies opened, the result is simply a loop of send/receive from each other signals (or think of it that way).

Comment: Thanks that's a great answer! Do you know how to isolate flash processes by any chance? I really don't like it when I can't run the program in two copies because of this. :(

Comment: You can't stop it doing what its programmed to do. I suspect it's even done  delibarate cos it's very unusual to find `localConnection()` being used. Why would someone go out of their way to make a notice of two copies being opened? Who knows, is this an exams type app you're using..?